# Is a unicode user agent legal inside an HTTP header?

Tags: mysql, http, user-agent

An application I'm maintaining loads user agents extracted from web logs into a MySQL table column using the 'latin1' charset. Occasionally, it fails to load a user agent that looks like this:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Iâ?; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML^C like Gecko) Version`

I suspect it's choking on `Iâ?`. I'm working to figure out if this should be supported, or if it's corruption introduced by the upstream logging system. Is this a legal user agent in a HTTP header?

Comment: The HTTP spec predates Unicode. I'm sure I saw some advice saying to output ASCII, but to accept UTF-8. But I don't recall where I saw that, which is why this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @TRiG: Sounds like a specific instance of the [Robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

Comment: In general it's probably a bad idea to try to store arbitrary data as Latin-1, unless you can guarantee that you'll only get input that can fit into the Latin-1 character set. Why aren't you using UTF-8?

Comment: @eggyal. Yes. I don't know where I saw this particular advice, but it certainly conforms to Postel's Law. And I'd bet it works fairly well.

Comment: @Wooble If the standard specifies only ASCII, I think it's reasonable to design a system that stores these values according to the standard. It looks like I have sanitizing work to do, however.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1) [says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) that message header contents must be *"consisting of either `*TEXT` or combinations of token, separators, and quoted-string"*. If you look at the [definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2) for TEXT etc you will find that legal characters are those with byte values not in the [0, 31] range and not equal to 127; therefore characters such as `â` are as far as I can tell legal as per the spec.

Comment: TEXT actually *does* allow octets > 127:

       TEXT           = <any OCTET except CTLs,
                        but including LWS>

Comment: @JulianReschke: Ouch. Should teach me to not read too quickly... I have corrected the answer; thank you for the catch.

Comment: Well 2012 was long time ago. Be aware that RFC 2616 is obsolete, see [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) instead. Particularly the last paragraph in [section 3.2.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.4).

Answer (score 4):

Technically, octets > 127 are allowed in comments. RFC 2616 makes them default to ISO-8859-1, but HTTPbis (the upcoming revision of RFC 2616) has removed that rule so that sometimes in the distant future, we may be able to move to a sane encoding.

Recommendation: strip all octets > 127.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 1.1 [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) refers to ISO-8859-1, which is a latin based single byte character set.

With the consideration that HTTP traffic is **supposed to be** single byte, I also am using the latin1 character set for my similar logs. The decision was simply to make my indexes smaller.

If you use UTF8 with VARCHAR, only the characters that are multi-byte require additional bytes, so in table space, it's not much extra. However, indexes are stored fixed-width, so, they're padded with spaces just in case you need them (UTF8 indexes are three times as large as latin1 indexes).

It doesn't affect me if the occasional odd header is unreadable. However, if you're not indexing the column, you may as well use UTF8.