# Are apache environment variables ASCII (as reflected in PHP $_SERVER)?

Tags: php, apache, unicode, environment-variables

I'm sanitizing USER_AGENT for logging in PHP and need to know whether to use substr() or mb_strcut().

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how `USER_AGENT` is directly derived from the HTTP request header `User-Agent`, I'm going to assume you're interested in HTTP headers.

Is it possible that HTTP headers will contain bytes outside the 7-bit ASCII range? [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384741/is-a-unicode-user-agent-legal-inside-an-http-header).

Is it likely that you'll actually see this in practice and need to handle it properly? I'd say no.

Therefore I suggest a third option: first strip all non-ASCII characters from the string, then use regular multibyte-unsafe functions to your heart's content.